# Python: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'function'

Tags: python

I am working on Jupyter Web and below is my code.

```
def get_hist(img, bins):
    histogram = np.zeros(bins)

    for pixel in im:
        histogram[pixel] += 1

    return get_hist

hist = get_hist(flat, 256)

plt.plot(hist)
```

And I am keep getting this problem.

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'function'
```

Any helpful advice?

Comment: You should do `return histogram` instead of `return get_hist`.

Comment: Thank you so much. your comment really did help me! Can I ask you one more question then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote a function that returns it's own function object. That won't provide much functionality or usability. You likely need to return `histogram`, which is what it seems your function intends to do.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can I ask you one more question regarding Python?

Comment: @Liz it's best to submit a new question for each question you have, that way it provides the most value to others and the community.

Comment: Ohhh okay. I just joined stack overflow and didn't know about it! I will submit a new question :) Thanks!